# Access a spinner selected item

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

I have a spinner with 2 items in it, but I want to use a different calculation when i select 1 of the items.

How do i acces 1 of my spinner items from another method?

It looks like this in my strings;

```
<string-array name="inputGender">
    <item> Kilo en centimeter</item>
    <item> Pounds and inches</item>
</string-array>
```

What i'am trying to do is use 2 different calculation for both my items. The calculations can be found in my calcBMI method.

My activity looks like this right now.

```
public class OpenBMI extends Activity {


private EditText heightIn;
private EditText weightIn;
private TextView bmiOut;
private TextView bmiStatus;
private Button calcBMI;
private double weight = 0;
private double height = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_open_bmi);
    initializeApp();

    //Spinner 2

    Spinner spinGender;

    //Gets spinner from layout
    spinGender = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinGender); 

    //Gets string for spinner
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, getResources()
                        .getStringArray(R.array.inputGender));


    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinGender.setAdapter(adapter);


        }

public void initializeApp() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    weightIn = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputWeight);
    heightIn = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputLength);
    calcBMI = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calcBMI);
    bmiOut = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bmiOut);
    bmiStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bmiStatus);

      calcBMI.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            calcBMI();
        }

    });         

}

public void calcBMI()
{

    String status;
    weight = Double.parseDouble( weightIn.getText().toString() );
    height = Double.parseDouble( heightIn.getText().toString() );
    double bmi = ( weight/(height * height));
    // double bmi2 = ( weight/(height * height) * 703);
    String result = String.format("%.2f", bmi);
    Log.d("MyActivity", result);

    bmiOut.setText(result, TextView.BufferType.NORMAL );


    if (bmi < 16.0){
        status = "Seriously Underweight";

    }else if ( bmi >= 16.0 && bmi < 18.0)
        {
            status = "Underweight";
        }else if ( bmi >=18.0 && bmi < 24.0){
            status = "normal";
        }else { status = "Overweight" ;
        }

    bmiStatus.setText(status);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access spinner value as

```
String value = spinGender.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

See more: [getSelectedItem()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getSelectedItem%28%29)

Answer (score 0):

Access spinner item as

```
String genderValue = spinGender.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

**implement the OnItemSelectedListener**
and then these 2 methods....

```
public class SpinnerActivity extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener {
    ...

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, 
            int pos, long id) {
        // An item was selected. You can retrieve the selected item using
        // parent.getItemAtPosition(pos)
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        // Another interface callback
    }
}
```